# Two computers on my home network. One is 10x slower to respond when I SSH in. Why?

Tags: ssh

Both computers are old clunkers I keep around for fun. When I use Putty to SSH to each of them one is very responsive and acts as expected. The other seems to have an incredible amount of lag, even just when entering the password for access. When I am using the machines in person (no SSH) both are very responsive (no lag).

Both use the same version of Ubuntu. The slow one has a few more packages installed (but plenty of disk space).

Are there any good diagnostics I can run that might show me something is causing the significant lag with TrashComputer2?

Answer (score 0):

Try investigating the system load averages on both machines. You can see them when you run `uptime`. It might also be worth running something like `htop` or `glances` to investigate what, if anything, is hogging resources. This type of lag is normally caused by an overloaded server, or networking issues.